# Simplify the Merge Question UI

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, merged-questions, moderator-tools

[image: Merge question UI]

This UI hurts to use.  To illustrate, let me describe the process by which someone arrives at this particular bit of UI:

1. someone notes that two questions are exactly the same.
2. A mod sees the flag, then opens both questions to review.
3. The mod determines both questions should be merged.
4. The mod knows they will face this bit of UI, so the mod goes to the master question url and starts playing "try to select only the digits from the url".
5. After the game is complete, the mod goes to the duplicated question and hits the Merge link.

It takes a bit of time to get just the post number and nothing else from a question's URL (step 4).  Occasionally, I'll find myself giving up on the mouse and using the keyboard to finish selection because I'm fighting the location textbox or am having problems targeting the selection start and end points.

**I'd suggest allowing for either the post number OR the post URL as valid input.**

Comment: Considering closing as duplicates allows either the Id or the URL, it seems feasible to update it in that kind of fashion.

Comment: This should also be extended to the "convert answers to comments" textbox - much easier to get the URL of another answer than to get its ID.

Comment: @Oak afaik (on SO) you can use the whole URL.  It wasn't working when the option appeared, but it works now.

Comment: Also, has anybody ever used those "Lookup Question" links?